# How to Install Reference Dependencies when Recursively Building in Typescript

Tags: typescript, npm, tsc

I'm trying to recursively build my project with "tsc --build". This only works if I've already installed dependencies in my referenced project. Otherwise, I get a build failure. I'm looking for a way to automagically install referenced project dependencies using npm or tsc.

So far, I've looked at npm recursive-install (https://www.npmjs.com/package/recursive-install). This doesn't solve my problem since my referenced project is not in a subdirectory of my top-level project. My use-case for referenced projects is to have a single "shared" project that contains shared constants for multiple top-level projects. Since I have multiple top-level projects, I cannot make my referenced project a subdirectory of all of them.

I have also considered using an external tool like Make to install dependencies, but this seems overly complex.

Comment: Your deps should be npm modules. You can then install them by referencing their git repo if not publicly posted.

Comment: @im_baby I think there is confusion about what I mean by "referenced project". I am referring to the tsc construct described here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html. My problem is that I have to manually "npm install" in all referenced projects before running "npm run build" in the top-level project I want to build. Basically, I'm looking for some kind of "tsc --install" that reclusively installs referenced project dependencies in the same way that "tsc --build" recursively builds the referenced projects.

Comment: According to the documentation that is exactly the behavior you should get. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html#build-mode-for-typescript.

Comment: @im_baby The documentation is ambiguous. It says that "tsc --build" builds dependencies, but it doesn't specify whether that only includes referenced projects, or if it also includes the dependencies listed in package.json. When I run "tsc --build" on my machine, it does not install dependencies listed in the package.json of the referenced project. Because it is consistent with one interpretation of the documentation, I'm assuming that the behavior I'm observing is intended.